# Cannot modify page layouts in SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, solution-package

We have a SharePoint solution developed by a vendor that does not allow me to make open and save a page layout with SharePoint Designer with out the thing blowing up.

What would cause this type of behaviour?

The same vendor developed another solution for another company I was at that experienced the same issue, so I am wondering what it is about there solutions  that cause this?

Comment: Their page layouts may have been developed with Visual Studio and are part of the solution package, so that you cannot change them with the front-end tools like SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Understood, but is there anyway to circumvent that?